# Ubuntu 18.04 error Unable to locate package build_essentials

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to build NREL's PV SAM for Ubuntu via their step by step directions at https://github.com/NREL/SAM/wiki/Linux-Build-Instructions.  I am stuck at Step 1.2 that specifies installing the a list of packages, including build_essential, but also libgtk2.0-dev, libgl1-mesa-dev, mesa-common-dev, freeglut3-dev and libcur14-openssl-dev.

All the packages load except build_essential, which throws the error: Unable to locate package build_essential.  I found others had asked the same questions, with responses/solutions focusing on enabling Ubuntu Bionic's main repository.  I tried all those procedures but still get the same message.

I assume the problem is at my end and that nothing has changed in Ubuntu 18.04, but I don't know this to be true, so I thought I'd send up a flare and hope for some kindness from strangers!

I am running a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an AMD powered laptop.  I've spent the last several days loading stuff onto it, but haven't seen this issue so before.

Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 2):

The package is called `build-essential`, see [this search result](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=build-essential&searchon=names). You're asking for `build_essential` (with an underscore `_`).